# On an infinite set, are all $n$-to-$n$ functions injective, and conversely?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be an infinite set, and let $f$ be a function from $S$ to $S$. Given a positive integer $n \geq 2$, $f$ is said to be $n$-to-$n$ if, for any $n$-element subset $T$ of $S$, the image $f(T)$ of $T$ also has $n$-elements. I want to know, given positive integers $m$ and $n$ both greater than or equal to $2$, is it true that $f$ is an $n$-to-$n$ function if and only $f$ is an $m$-to-$m$ function if and only if $f$ is injective?

Comment: Have you really asked what you mean to? On any set $S$ whatsoever, a function $f$ is injective iff it satisfies $\vert f(X)\vert=\vert X\vert$ for all $X\subseteq S$, and conversely if $f$ is $2$-to-$2$ then $f$ is injective. So all these variations collapse and the size of $S$ is uninvolved.

Comment: @NoahSchweber what do you mean? If $S$ has $n$ elements, then an $n$-to-$n$ function won't necessarily be injective, it can be any function. The size assumption is definitely necessary.

Comment: @Jakobian you mean less than $n$ elements? If $S$ has at least $n$ elements it should also hold?

Comment: @psl2Z ah sorry. Yes, I suppose we should be taking a set of less than $n$ elements to make it trivially an $n$-to-$n$ function. It was a mistake by me.

Comment: @Jakobian Sorry, I meant to restrict attention to $\vert S\vert\ge n$ of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be an $(n+1)$-to-$(n+1)$ function and $A = \{x_1, ..., x_n\}\subseteq S$ be any $n$-element set. Pick any $x\in S\setminus A$, then $f[A\cup \{x\}] = f[A]\cup \{f(x)\}$ has $n+1$ elements. Since $f[A]$ can have size at most $n$, it must have size precisely $n$. Thus $f$ is an $n$-to-$n$ function.

By descending like this, $f$ must be a $2$-to-$2$ function. If now $x\neq y$ then it follows that $f(x)\neq f(y)$, so $f$ is injective.

The converse, that all injective functions are $n$-to-$n$ functions is obvious.

Comment: Well, $1$-to-$1$ functions, under my definition, are not necessarily injective. For EVERY function $f$, the image of a singleton is a singleton. Injective functions satisfy the property, $x \neq y \implies f(x) \neq f(y)$.

Comment: @user107952 sorry for that mistake! Thankfully $2$-to-$2$ functions can be easily seen to be injective so my argument still works.

Comment: There doesn't need to be an extra step to go from 2-to-2 to 1-to-1; the argument in the first paragraph is already valid when $n=1$.

Comment: @GregMartin it might be a little confusing, but $1$-to-$1$ function in this context isn't the same as injective function. It's a function that maps every one-element set to a one-element set, thus its any function. Instead, injective functions are precisely $2$-to-$2$ functions.

Comment: aha good point.